# Create executable and shared library with one makefile

Tags: compiling, make, executable, shared-library

Using makefiles is new to me. My first tests with the simplest approach worked very well so far. But now I got stuck writing a makefile that creates a executable file and a shared library. As I said I'm new to makefiles. Here is my simple approach:

```
exe.a: main.c func.c
    gcc main.c func.c -o exe.a
lib.so: func.c
    gcc func.c -o lib.so -fPIC -shared
```

When the makefile is executed only the executable will be compiled. Is it even possible to create two objects with one makefile? What is the best approach to create these files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `make` will build only the *first* target in a Makefile
which is `exe.a` in your case. You can either tell `make` to create
another target:

```
make lib.so
```

or both targets:

```
make lib.so exe.a
```

or (preferred) introduce a new *first target* which is usually named
`all`:

```
all: exe.a lib.so

exe.a: main.c func.c
    gcc main.c func.c -o exe.a
lib.so: func.c
    gcc func.c -o lib.so -fPIC -shared
```

Now a simple `make` will build the (pseudo-) target `all` which in turn
depends on `exe.a` and `lib.so`, so they get built first. Note that you
must not have a file called `all` in your directory in this case because
then `make` gets confused.

Comment: Thank you. The option with the new first target is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Olupo You are welcome. When you study other Makefiles you'll encounter this `all` target very often.

Comment: I've read some other makefiles, but most of them were to advanced for my current skill level.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean :-) My skills aren't very good either and when it comes to more complicated Makefiles I usually think of them as _rocket science_.